# How to properly delete messages and calls history with particular contact in Skype database?

Tags: database, sqlite, skype

I would like to delete history of chats (i.e. messages) and records of calls/video calls for particular contact in the Skype database. I do the following queries:

```
delete from messages where author='particular_contact_nick'
delete from messages where dialog_partner='particular_contact_nick'
```

But I have the following problems:

1. It deletes message on the device where I do it, messages
   remains on other devices with the same account;
2. Looks like when my `particular_contact_nick` is online, my deleted messages are
   restored; probably not
   deletion, but replacement of messages with spaces will help?
3. It deletes only messages, records of calls/video calls history ('Call with particular_contact_nick, length: 00:15') are not deleted.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The databases are local but synchronised with the remote one, and they will get synchronised again every time you open Skype. There's no way you can delete something and will be removed from the remote database.